# iTextSharp StyleSheet equivalent

Tags: itext

When using the `HTMLWorker` to covert HTML into PDF elements we can provide a `StyleSheet` instance that can be used to style the generated elements.

Unfortunately the CSS-to-PDF conversion is quite limited (it doesn't seem possible to indent a list for example) so I wondered if there is an equivalent iTextSharp "PDF Stylesheet" we can declare, which will be used when elements are written to the document?

Alternatively are there any events we can hook into in order to walk the element tree and apply our styles, before the document is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as documented on many places (especially on SO), HTMLWorker is deprecated in favor of [XML Worker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/). XML Worker reads CSS from file, from the header, inline, etc... Read [the documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) for more info about the Java version. For the C# version, take a look at the [test apps](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker.testApps/html2pdf/).

Comment: I want to apply styles to elements that I create manually in addition to those generated by the parser so can't rely on the HTML/XML worker for this. Is it not possible to set global styles for a document?

Comment: Global styles are applied by introducing a global CSS (one that isn't referred to from the HTML file).

Comment: And how do I apply the "global" stylesheet?

Comment: By loading a custom CSS file into the CSSResolver: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-14

Comment: Okay but this assumes I'm using an XML/HTML file as input. My question is whether I can specify a stylesheet that will be applied when using the managed api e.g. `Document.AddParagraph(...)`

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question. You confused me by talking about HTML. Why didn't you just ask: is there a way to set default fonts, font sizes, etc... for high-level objects. The answer to this question is no, there isn't. In my book, I create objects using an ElementFactory. That's the best way to create Elements in a specific style.

Comment: I wanted to give my question context. I'll have a look into `ElementFactory`.